# Change standard error color for geom_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting some data using geom_smooth and looking for a way to change the color of the standard error shading for each line to match that line (ie., a red line would have it's standard error shaded red).

I've looked through the official ggplot2 documentation as well as the list of opts() at https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/%2Bopts%28%29-List.

Any advice (or just confirmation of whether or not it's possible) is appreciated.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Your (understandable) mistake is to think that you should be changing the *color* rather than the *fill*. The standard error shadings are made with `geom_ribbon` essentially, and they are a 2d area, so the "color" they are "filled" with is determined by `fill`, not `colour`.

Try:

```
geom_smooth(aes(...,fill = variable))
```

where variable is the same one you map to colour elsewhere.

Comment: How to handle interactions? I am using `ggplot( ... aes(... color=interaction(a,b))) + geom_smooth(... fill=interaction(a,b))` but I get error: `object 'a' not found'`. Classic unpredictable behaviour in this abominable "language".

Answer (score 5):

If you have multiple groups you simple define `color = Vars` and `group = Vars` within `ggplot(aes())`, and then additional `aes(fill = Vars)` within `geom_smooth(aes(fill = Species))`. ([Based on answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52888292/how-to-set-the-color-of-seconfidence-interval-of-geom-smooth-in-ggplot2))

Dummy example:

```
# Make confidence intervals the same color as line by group
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, 
                 y = Sepal.Width, 
                 group = Species,
                 color = Species)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(aes(fill = Species))  # additional `aes()` referencing to confidence interval as a `fill` not as a `color`
```

[image]