# How to set the color of se(confidence interval) of geom_smooth in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I set the function, `geom_smooth(..., se = TRUE)`, the confidence interval is gray, but I want to set some other color.

Looks like it is a parameter that can not set color in geom_smooth. Should I create a new geom? or are there some ggplot2 extensions can be used?
Thank you

Answer (score 25):

Since you did not provide example data

```
ggplot(
    iris, 
    aes(
        x = Sepal.Length, 
        y = Sepal.Width
    )
) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_smooth(fill = "red")
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Surprisingly it's easy to  solve! Thank you very much !